# jQuery slideToggle first of class below

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row header collapse">
     Content 1
     <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up" ></i>
</div>

<div class="instructions-container">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
</div>

<div class="row header collapse">
     Content 2
     <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up" ></i>
</div>

<div class="instructions-container">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
</div>
```

Basically, I have multiple instances of this setup on one page, but on click of `.collapse`, I want to `slideToggle` **ONLY** the `.instructions-container` that is directly below the clicked collapse button.

I'd also like to toggle rotate the `.fa-chevron-cirle-up` 180 degrees on click as well, but again, only this clicked one.

Here is the current jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('.collapse').click(function () {
          $(this).find('.instructions-container').slideToggle();
     });
});
```

Comment: Try `$(this).find(".fas").toggleClass("fa-rotate-180")`  https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/rotating-icons

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the first half with the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('.collapse').click(function () {
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
   });

});
```